# How can I change the default value for the 'assigned to' a speicifc value in the ' Queue'?

Tags: tasks, fsl

The default value of the 'Assign to' should be a particular 'x' value in the Queue. In this way the user will no longer have to click the down arrow next to 'Assign to' -> Select Queues -> Select 'x' value as presented in the attached image.
Thanks in advance for all the answers!

[image]

Comment: Sounds like great feature request -- define a default lookup values for quick assignment in Lightning (for Owners -- Users/Queues)